# SQL Point wrong Insert / Select

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to create a SQL database with coordinations, which look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE automaten_loc( 
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
location POINT  NOT NULL, 
primary key(ID) );
```

I inserted some data:

```
INSERT INTO automaten_loc (location) 
VALUES (POINT(12.34567, 76.54321));
```

But select * returns this:

[image]

Im not so good with SQL, and I have no idea what's wrong...

Do you know why?
Thank you :)

Comment: let me know your mysql version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This to get x cordinate and y conrdinate

```
SELECT x(location),y(location) FROM test.automaten_loc;

mysql> SELECT x(location),y(location) FROM test.automaten_loc;
+-------------+-------------+
| x(location) | y(location) |
+-------------+-------------+
|    12.34567 |    76.54321 |
+-------------+-------------+

mysql> SELECT x(location),y(location),concat(x(location),', ',y(location)) FROM test.automaten_loc;
+-------------+-------------+---------------------------------+
| x(location) | y(location) | concat(x(location),y(location)) |
+-------------+-------------+---------------------------------+
|    12.34567 |    76.54321 | 12.34567, 76.54321                |
+-------------+-------------+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

I execute this at my system

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID, CONCAT(ST_X(location),',',ST_Y(location)) as loc FROM automaten_loc
```